# How not to display all x axis coordinate labels pyqt5

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qtcharts

From time to time I returned to the code that [eyllanesc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6622587/eyllanesc) helped me with.

Need to display every 6 placemarks on the axis.
It would also be better to display datetime(**date**)

```
[datetime.date(1991, 2, 4) datetime.date(1991, 2, 5)
 datetime.date(1991, 2, 6) ... datetime.date(2019, 7, 31)
 datetime.date(2019, 8, 1) datetime.date(2019, 8, 2)]
```

instead of indexes

```
(0, 1, 2, 3....70)
```

When displaying datetime data in C#, I used string data, since on weekends datetime was also displayed and empty spaces on the axis Y were obtained.
Python will probably have the same data datetime problems.
The data file is located here [file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1trfarfC54SeO41XN5SChJogqLwTHO6ku/view)

I displayed what I wanted to do in the image.

P.S. Made the code shorter for better understanding.
[image]

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, QtChart
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
import math
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('file.txt',
                         index_col='DATE',
                         parse_dates=True,
                         infer_datetime_format=True)


date = df.iloc[:, 0].index.date
o = df.iloc[:, 0].values
h = df.iloc[:, 1].values
l = df.iloc[:, 2].values
z = df.iloc[:, 3].values
x = len(z)
x_ = x - 1

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.step = 30
        self._chart_view = QtChart.QChartView()
        self.scrollbar = QtWidgets.QScrollBar(
            QtCore.Qt.Horizontal,
            sliderMoved=self.onAxisSliderMoved,
            pageStep=self.step,
        )


        self.scrollbar.setRange(0, x_)

        central_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)

        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(central_widget)
        for w in (self._chart_view, self.scrollbar):
            lay.addWidget(w)

        self._chart = QtChart.QChart()
        self._candlestick_serie = QtChart.QCandlestickSeries()
        self._candlestick_serie.setDecreasingColor(Qt.red)
        self._candlestick_serie.setIncreasingColor(Qt.green)

        tm = []

        for i in range(0, len(z)):
            o_ = o[i]
            h_ = h[i]
            l_ = l[i]
            c_ = z[i]
            self._candlestick_serie.append(QtChart.QCandlestickSet(o_, h_, l_, c_))
            tm.append(str(i))

        min_x, max_x = 0, x_

        self._chart.addSeries(self._candlestick_serie)
        self._chart.createDefaultAxes()
        self._chart.legend().hide()
        self._chart.axisX(self._candlestick_serie).setCategories(tm)
        self._chart_view.setChart(self._chart)
        self.lims = np.array([min_x, max_x])
        self.onAxisSliderMoved(self.scrollbar.value())
        self.adjust_axes(1, 30)


    def adjust_axes(self, value_min, value_max):
        if value_min > 0 and value_max > 0 and value_max <= x_ and value_max > value_min:
            self._chart.axisX(self._candlestick_serie).setRange(str(value_min), str(value_max))

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(int)
    def onAxisSliderMoved(self, value):
        value2 = value + self.step
        value1 = value
        if value2 >= x_:
            value2 = x_
            value1 = value2 - self.step
        self.adjust_axes(math.floor(value1), math.ceil(value2))



if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I tried to determine the axes separately, but nothing comes out. Code below.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, QtChart
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtChart import *
import math
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import datetime

df = pd.read_csv('file.txt',
                         index_col='DATE',
                         parse_dates=True,
                         infer_datetime_format=True)


date = df.iloc[:, 0].index.date
o = df.iloc[:, 0].values
h = df.iloc[:, 1].values
l = df.iloc[:, 2].values
z = df.iloc[:, 3].values
x = len(z)
x_ = x - 1

qt = [None] * x
for i in range(0, x):
   qt[i] = (date[i].strftime("%Y/%m/%d"))


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.step = 30
        self._chart_view = QtChart.QChartView()
        self.scrollbar = QtWidgets.QScrollBar(
            QtCore.Qt.Horizontal,
            sliderMoved=self.onAxisSliderMoved,
            pageStep=self.step,
        )


        self.scrollbar.setRange(0, x_)

        central_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)

        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(central_widget)
        for w in (self._chart_view, self.scrollbar):
            lay.addWidget(w)

        self._chart = QtChart.QChart()
        self._candlestick_serie = QtChart.QCandlestickSeries()

        for i in range(0, len(z)):
            o_ = o[i]
            h_ = h[i]
            l_ = l[i]
            c_ = z[i]
            _time = qt[i]
            self._candlestick_serie.append(QtChart.QCandlestickSet(o_, h_, l_, c_, _time))

        min_x, max_x = 0, x_

        self._chart.addSeries(self._candlestick_serie)
        self._chart.legend().hide()
        #self._chart.createDefaultAxes()


        axisX = QDateTimeAxis()
        axisX.setTickCount(5)
        axisX.setFormat("dd.MM.yyyy")
        self._chart.addAxis(axisX, Qt.AlignBottom)
        self._candlestick_serie.attachAxis(axisX)

        # Y Axis Settings
        axisY = QValueAxis()
        axisY.setLabelFormat("%i")
        self._chart.addAxis(axisY, Qt.AlignLeft)
        self._candlestick_serie.attachAxis(axisY)


        self._chart_view.setChart(self._chart)
        self.lims = np.array([min_x, max_x])
        self.onAxisSliderMoved(self.scrollbar.value())
        self.adjust_axes(1, 31)
        #self._chart.axisX(self._candlestick_serie).setTickCount(7)


    def adjust_axes(self, value_min, value_max):
        if value_min > 0 and value_max > 0 and value_max <= x_ and value_max > value_min:
            self._chart.axisX(self._candlestick_serie).setRange(str(value_min), str(value_max))

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(int)
    def onAxisSliderMoved(self, value):
        value2 = value + self.step
        value1 = value
        if value2 >= x_:
            value2 = x_
            value1 = value2 - self.step
        self.adjust_axes(math.floor(value1), math.ceil(value2))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Matplotlib has an example where string values are set instead of indexes [enter link description here](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/gallery/text_labels_and_annotations/date_index_formatter.html#sphx-glr-gallery-text-labels-and-annotations-date-index-formatter-py)

Comment: Is there any way to call eyllanesc for help?
I think he knows a lot about pyqt.

I tried to figure out the code myself, but it doesn't work.
I assume that you need to declare the x, y axes separately.
And submit to the "QtChart.QCandlestickSet(o_, h_, l_, c_)" the fifth parameter from the x axis(tm or date).

Comment: If this is not possible in pyqt5, then also write. So as not to waste time.